# sencha android native app and facebook sdk

Tags: javascript, android, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, sencha-touch-2

I have a problem with my sencha app, it uses facebook sdk javascript to log in, of course in the browser it works perfectly because facebook authorizes the domain name. but when i turn my app into a native android app, facebook rejects the app saying the given url is not allowed.

I have tried authorizing it as a native android app getting the key hash from the keystore I used, and putting in the facebook app  with no success maybe i am missing something i would greatly appreciate any help in pointing me in the right direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it using the facebook connect plugin for phonegap and phonegap created by dave johnson

its in git hub

https://github.com/davejohnson/phonegap-plugin-facebook-connect/

Answer (score -1):

You need to use the FB JavaScript library, not connect... Your best bet is to look at Jog With Friends in the ST2 examples directory to see how integration is handled

Comment: I am using the javascript library, the problem is that when the app is packaged native for android it does not connect to a domain therefore facebook does not authorize the app to connect to facebook, but i can not use the android FB sdk because my app is developed in javascript. any ideas?